# How write Create and Update Query in Room Library?

Tags: android, performance, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room

I go through SQL query other solution. i am not able to find suitable solutions for my problem.

In My project, i have the insert data into the table. I have to follow some steps
Step1:- I have to check data through a primary key that the data is available or not.
Step 2: if data is available then I have to update that data and return response code. if not I have to go step 3
Step 3: if data is not in the table then insert data into it and return code.

I am using Room Library. i am confused how to write in @Dao to perform that task.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android Architecture Components introduced Android Room Persistence Library which is best for sqlite android database handling. Entity in Room Persistence represents a database table and Dao is where we define database interactions. Example

```
@Entity
public class Trail {
       public @PrimaryKey String id;
       public String name;
       public double kilometers;
       public int difficulty;
}
```

possible Dao for this table will be

```
@Dao
public interface TrailDao {

       @Insert(onConflict = IGNORE)
       void insertTrail(Trail trail);

       @Query("SELECT * FROM Trail")
       List<Trail> findAllTrails();

       @Update(onConflict = REPLACE)
       void updateTrail(Trail trail);

      @Query("DELETE FROM Trail")
      void deleteAll();
  }
```

Further you need to provide RoomDatabase implementation, Example

```
@Database(entities = {Trail.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    private static AppDatabase INSTANCE;

    public abstract TrailDao trailDao();

    public static AppDatabase getInMemoryDatabase(Context context) {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            INSTANCE =
Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class)

                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .build();
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public static void destroyInstance() {
        INSTANCE = null;
    }
}
```

Use It like

```
AppDatabase. getInMemoryDatabase(context).trailDao().findAllTrails();
```

Comment: @PrinceKumar there return type is void.

Comment: according to your code return type void but it support int return type also if its return value is 1 then your data is update else not update